# what is a "powerset" with base larger than 2?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

A powerset $P(S) $of some set $S$ can be treated as all different possible ways of partition $S$ into 2 ordered pair of disjoint subsets.

And I'm curious what is the equivalence of partition $S$ into more than 2 subsets?

For example, partition the set S into 3 ordered pair of disjoint subsets.

With $|S| \geq 3$, The cardinality should be $3^{|S|}$? And moreover what is the name of arbitrary base powersets?

Comment: What you write about the power set is not quite accurate, $P(S)$ is more like all possible ways to partition $S$ into *an ordered pair* of disjoint subsets. The generalization would be an ordered partition.

Comment: Of course the partitions $\{1\},\{2,3\}$ and $\{2,3\},\{1\}$ are considered to be different partitions of $\{1,2,3\}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The power set of $S$ is (by the usual definition) the set of subsets of $S$.
The fact that each subset can be paired with its complement is an interesting accident. You can think of each such pair as a partition into two blocks, but to recover the power set you have to be able to distinguish the blocks. That means you are looking at ordered partitions, as in the comment from @LeoMosher .

An equivalent definition of the power set is as the set of all functions
$$
f: S \to \{0,1\} .
$$
The proof follows from the fact that each subset is determined by and determines its characteristic function: the function that's $1$ on the subset and $0$ elsewhere.

So perhaps the natural generalization you seek is the set of functions
$$
f: S \to \{0,1,2\} .
$$
These correspond to ordered partitions into three blocks (with a little care taken since two of the blocks can be empty simultaneously).

Comment: Also there is some implicit assumption that $|S| \geq 3$ ? Otherwise it won’t have the $3^{|S|}$ choices?

Comment: @pengyu No. This works when $S$ has just one element. That element is mapped to $1$, $2$ or $3$. This case is a little tricky since the ordered partition will have two empty blocks. In fact, with the right interpretation of the empty set and the empty function, the argument works when $S$ is empty,

Comment: @pengyu: Under this logic, what would be the power set of a singleton, or god forbid, the empty set?

Comment: @AsafKaragila I’m not sure I follow can you elaborate?

Comment: @pengyu: If you need $|S|$ to be at least $3$ for $3^{|S|}$ to make sense as partitions into $3$ blocks, how do you make sense of $2^{|S|}$ when $S$ has no elements, or just one?

Comment: Ah yeah, I was mistaken about the empty set situation, every set comes with infinity many empty sets element when it comes to partition somehow

Answer (score 0):

Not a generalization of how the powerset is formed, but a version satisfying $A\subset B\Longrightarrow T(A)\subset T(B)$ would be
$$
T(A):=\bigcup_{A'\subset A}\{0,1\}^{A'}=\{\{(x,i(x)):x\in A'\}:A'\subset A,i:A'\to\{0,1\}\}.
$$
$T(A)$ can be seen like this: to form it, you pick every subset of $A$, but you have to paint each element in this subset either in red (when $i(x)=0$) or in blue (when $i(x)=1$).

This has cardinality $3^{|A|}$ because we have the natural bijection
$$
\{0,1,2\}^A\to T(A),\quad f\mapsto f|_{\{x\in A:f(x)\neq 2\}}.
$$